# Background хедера во всю страницу

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, как сделать, чтобы фоновая картинка шапки сайта (header) по высоте всегда была на 100% от монитора? Заранее спасибо

Comment: многие верстальщики стали делать отдельный блок для фона , и применяют для этого обычный img а если надо его прокручивать то делается параллакс ...

Comment: я все равно не понял как сделать то что я хочу

Comment: нужно код полностью видеть, так как не понятно какие там еще свойства есть, можете для начало прописать: background-size: cover;

Comment: никаких свойств нету, шапка ведь первое что делается в сайте)

Comment: @Павел Румянцев, и оцентровать ее background-position: center center;

Comment: @ПавелРумянцев  примерно так :https://jsfiddle.net/0xnzkf59/7/

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, у вас тег header тянется на весь экран. Чтобы точно задать ему размер по высоте занимать ровно один экран, можете использовать свойство стиля `height: 100vh;` 
Для более наглядного примера: http://jsfiddle.net/0L8esn1t/4/

Answer (score 0):

Нужно прописать для фонового блока высоту равную высоте одного экрана - **height: 100vh;** и так же **background-size: cover**; - для масштабирования картинки на весь блок с учетом пропорций